# The project YYY does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path

Tags: android, eclipse, gwt, maven

Eclipse has a problem that it is reporting to me:

> The project XXX does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path

...and I am having a terrible time figuring out where this problem is coming from and how to resolve it.

The first thing you need to know is that the project that I'm working on is not a GWT project, nor has it ever been one.  Instead, this is an android project, which uses a Maven POM to organize its settings.

GWT is mentioned nowhere in the POM, nor is it mentioned in ".classpath" or ".project" - or, for that matter, anywhere in any file under the root of my project.

So Eclipse is clearly misguided in some way.   None of the standard answers in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path) seem to apply to my situation.

Comment: Have you checked your imports. Maybe an automatic import by Content Assist in Eclipse used a GWT library that is non-existent in your classpath.

Comment: Looking Similar Threads! You can find solution here...

[The project XXX does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out.  It turns out that another member of the team found an offending gwt-related line in the .project file.  They fixed & committed their change, which is why I was unable to see anything there.   Meanwhile, my Eclipse never caught on to the fact that the offending line was removed, so what I had to do was right-click on the problem in the problems tab and delete that particular problem.  From then on, my Eclipse was no longer confused.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put following lines into your `.classpath` file

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
```

Then right click on your **project** and select **refresh** (or simply <kbd>F5</kbd>).

After this, go to your **project** and select **clean**. It should automatically rebuild all your project.