# Errors while setting up LibGDX on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have been trying to setup LibGDX on Eclipse (4.3). I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Prerequisites and installed both ADT plugin for Eclipse and the Google Web toolkit successfully. Then I used the libgdx-ui.exe to create the libGDX project and on creating it, I see errors in Eclipse.

[image]

I am pretty sure I have installed the plugins properly and I have JDK 7 as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

It seems I have not installed the GWT plugins properly. But on trying to install it from the link, the option to install the SDK does not appear in the list.(Please check the image in the last comment I posted).

Comment: Check with one of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path

Comment: Hi Lestat, thanks for the reply.

I tried the above link but I don't know how exactly to proceed with the first step 'Remove all GWTs from your build path.'

And in the second step while I click 'Configure SDKs..', there are no SDK's listed. HOw should I proceed?

Comment: Maybe these screenshots will help you: http://s21.postimg.org/iwu9oqz1z/instant2.png http://s21.postimg.org/dmpaxget3/instant3.png if you don't see the sdk, you probably didn't install the gwt plugin correctly. Also you will find the error described in this video: http://youtu.be/mmH05k6HFsI?t=8m11s

Comment: Oh that helped. So I guess I have not properly installed the GWT plugin. Here is a screenie: http://s8.postimg.org/6fsprwgkl/asd.jpg But it's so strange because when I tried to install GWT, first it showed me a download timeout error so I downloaded a zip file and used it to do an offline install which succeeded as well.

Is there someway I can remove all traces of GWT and start over again?

Comment: did you follow these instructions? http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html

Comment: Did you try the fix of the video? does the sdk appear now in the properties?

Comment: Yes I did follow the instructions in that page. However, I just noticed the SDK option does not appear for me to install it :| http://s22.postimg.org/ncfy98j41/asd.gif and when I proceed with the installtion, http://s28.postimg.org/malkb8akd/untitled.png


In the quick fix window, the synchronize WAR ... option is not present. I have two options to Configure build path or to replace it with other library. I think I still have not installed the SDK properly.

Comment: And here are the properties for the html file - http://i.imgur.com/t7doAFH.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Android requires (before kitkat) jdk 6. It won't work with jdk 7.
2) After installing ADT plugin, you also have to open android sdk manager and download required api files.

These two should fix your android and java.lang.Object issues. It's better to test an android app on this setup (without libgdx) first.

3) Right click on all warnings regarding classpath entries, eclipse will provide you automatic quick fixes.

If the issue stays after this, the problem is with gwt sdk installation. Now you can follow [The project XXX does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path). It should work smoothly as other problems won't interfere with it now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Tanmay Patil,
You were right. Some guys from the IRC helped me out with the problem. The main problem I had was that I did not install the GWT SDK but only the plugin for eclipse. And then I also download android plugin 4.4 which fixed up all the errors. Thanks for the reply :)