# Application will not compile after updating GWT Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have just updated my GWT Eclipse plugin and now I get the following error when I try to compile:

An internal error occurred during: "AwardTracker_N - GWT Compile".
java.lang.NullPointerException

I have not made any changes to the code since the last compile before the update.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
GWT 2.7.0

I have found this error "Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project 'AwardTracker_N' does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path   AwardTracker_N      Unknown GWT Problem".

In the project's Properties under Java Build Path (Libraries) I have "GWT SDK [GWT 2.7.0 - 2.7.0]" and "GWT SDK [GWT 2.8.1 - 2.8.1]"

In the project's Properties under GWT - General Settings I have "Use GWT" checked, selected "Use default SDK (GWT 2.7.0 - 2.7.0)"

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: [The project XXX does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path)

I moved "GWT SDK [GWT 2.7.0 - 2.7.0]" and "GWT SDK [GWT 2.8.1 - 2.8.1]" to the top using the re-order tab.